# Lambda expressions in depth

Tags: .net, lambda

I'm interested in mastering Lambda expressions. I want to gain a deep understanding of the topic. I've searched web for books devoted solely for them but didn't find.

If someone wants to learn MSIL he has an option to look at the book *Inside Microsoft .NET IL Assembler*. It is published in 2002 but anyway it gives a solid insight into the topic.

Can somebody tell me is there any book devoted for lambda expressions in .NET, (doesn't matter C# or VB.) If there is not are there some resorces online which give a comprehensive, step by step explanation?

The more useful links, the better.

Comment: I found Jon Skeet's "C# in Depth" helpful.

Comment: Are you interested in the theory or how they are implemented in .NET (C#, VB.NET, etc.)?

Comment: It seems unlikely that there's be an entire book about lambda expressions - they're really not that complicated. Assuming you understand the basics, how variables are captured, and that lambda expressions can be converted into both delegates and expression trees, what else do you need to know?

Comment: @JonSkeet I want fully understand expression trees and parse them. For example in the nearest future I want to implement IQueryable for SOLR.

Comment: @Oybek: Right, well expression trees and lambda expressions aren't the same thing. I still doubt that you'll find a book about expression trees, but you should be able to find quite a lot of detail on MSDN.

Comment: how about this http://bloggingcsharpindepth.blogspot.com/2013/03/lambda-expressions-and-expression-trees.html

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps understanding [functional programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) in general and read a bit about [lambda calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) could be relevant.

Very probably, [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) should interest you (even if it is not about C#). And maybe, learning some more functional programming language like Scheme, Ocaml, Haskell (and perhaps F#).